# do I need fsck.ext4 before mounting a filesystem?

Tags: filesystems, mount, ext4, fsck

I have a script that mounts `/dev/sdc1` to `/home`. I do not know the state of `/dev/sdc1` in advance, it could possibly be "dirty". Do I need to run  fsck.ext4 before mounting the filesystem, or has mount some checks that will prevent a "dirty" filesystem to be mounted an possibly corrupting data?

Or even better, is there some way to tell mount to check the filesystem when mounting ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There used to be an option to check `ext2` filesystems at mount time, but that is no longer supported. Nowadays boot scripts check filesystems before mounting them, and your scripts should do so too. Mounting a filesystem does still check things to make sure it's safe to mount the filesystem; but it won't fix anything (beyond replaying the journal on `ext3` or `ext4` filesystems).

You should use `fsck -p` to perform these checks; the `-p` option tells `e2fsck` to fix anything that can be fixed safely without human intervention. If an error occurs requiring human intervention, `e2fsck` will exit with an appropriate exit code, and your script needs to take those into account as well.

See the `mount(8)`, `fsck(8)` and `fsck.ext4(8)` manpages for more details. You might find the source code of [`ext4_fill_super()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/ext4/super.c?v=4.0#L3409) interesting; that's the code which mounts an `ext4` filesystem.